# Oracle Apex 5: How do I redirect page when (dynami-action)button clicked?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a dilemna. I want to redirect the APP_USER to another page when a button is clicked. The thing is the button has a dynamic action with PLSQL body. The PLSQL does a few checks and validations and then redirects the individual to another page. How would I do that? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you tried to use a Branch that is conditioned by the validations in your PLSQL code?

Comment: don't know how to do that. Could you explain a little please? Thank you for responding btw. Really grateful.

Comment: @Cristian_I it's a dynamic action plsl on the button btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use Branches because they are easier and better from a security point of view.

On your page create a button that will submit the page (has attribute **Action**=**Submit Page**) then create a **Branch** at the **Processing** point where you will select the page that you want the user to be redirected to.

Now to make this branch run just in some conditions go to the **Condition** attribute of the branch and at **When Button Pressed** select your button and at **Type** select **PLSQL Function Body** and add your logic there or select some other type that suits you best.

Comment: Thank you. I understood and did exactly that. The issue is it brings back an error saying redirecting too many times or something. I have a branch in pre header of home page. So when someone logs in, it checks to see what page to redirect them to. ends up not working. I'm using this code for redirection >> owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&APP_SESSION.');
apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

Comment: not sure if you'll get notified of my reply without me using yourusername

Comment: this is the error apex.oracle.com redirected you too many times.

Comment: @AbdirizakObsiye That's all info that really should have been in your question: it's what you have tried and hasn't succeeded. I suggest you edit your question, include that info, and then please expand on your redirect mechanism and what is supposed to achieve. For instance, don't you want deeplinking enabled? Where are you redirecting who to, and on what basis?